# PHP convert content to separate arrays

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I'm working on a fairly simple website where you can upload a file with some kind of info and the website analyses this data, returns certain values like averages, a bar plot etc.
All is well with the ladder, but I'm struggling to read the info and convert it to arrays.
In this case I have a .txt file with daily temperatures of December.
I need to put these values into separate arrays, however whenever I use implode, the array is split simply into rows. Here's the var_dump;

```
 array(7) { 
[0]=> string(107) "0    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015 " 
[1]=> string(107) " 1   3.4 7.4 8.3 5.9 10.4    10.8    8.6 6.6 6.7 9.9 6.2 9.1 11  7   5.4 5.4 8.7 4   9.4 5.9 8.2 2   0.7 9.6 6.9 3.2 10.4" 
[2]=> string(107) " 9.3 6.5 4.1 7.8 7.2 5.7 0.3 8.6 4.5 2.6 6.6 8.6 8.2 9   7.2 10.4 3  1.6 10.9    0.9 4   10  7.1 10.7    2.1 7.4 4   7.7" 
[3]=> string(107) " -1.6    8.4 0.8 -0.3    8.9 5.6 6.5 9.5 8   10 4    -0.2    11.1    1.7 2.2 9.7 9.8 9.9 -0.2    9.6 6   8.8 1.5 5.5 1.4 -0.7    9." 
[4]=> string(107) "3    6.9 7   8.9 8.6 7.8 5   1.2 11.1    -0.1    6.8 8.5 9.2 7.8 0.1 8.9 9.5 8.5 -2.3    2.8 4.2 1   7.6 6.4 6.1 9   7.3 7.8 " 
[5]=> string(107) "6    7.2 9.6 1.1 4.8 4.8 6.4 6.1 3.7 6.7 7.8 9.7 2.2 1.7 3.8 1.8 7   5.8 6.7 8.8 8.5 5.4 7   1.6 9.9 6.6 3.4 5.2 " 
[6]=> string(107) "8.7  7.3 1.1 3.4 3.3 7.5 10  5   2.2 2.4 4.6 4.1 7.4 6.9 9.6 3.8 8   -1.6    7.9 9   3.1 5.2 9.6 6.3 1.2 3.1 1.6 7.5 " 
}
```

I need to skip whitespace & tabs when they're there and whenever there's a numerical or floating point, put them into the same array element.
For example, we've got 4.5 2.7 5, I need 4.5 to be one element, then 2.7 to be the other, etc.
I've tried using ifs with the conditions mentioned, however, it did not work.
I feel like there's a small amount of syntax I'm not yet familiar with or maybe a function I overlooked.

Here's the clean code I've got so far;

```
<?php

$getcont = file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\gruodis.txt');
$contstr = str_split($getcont);

$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$c = 0;
$d = 0;
$sum = 0;
$contarr = array();

//fix the < values

for ($a = 0; $a < 7; $a++){
                for ($b = 0; $b < 107; $b++){
                    $contarr[$a][$b] = $contstr[$c];
                    $c++;                   
        }
        echo '<br>';
}
echo '<br><br>';

foreach ($contarr as $key => $value){
        $val = implode($value);
        $contarr[$key] = $val;
}

var_dump($contarr);

?>
```

Here's the content I'm using;
https://pastebin.com/QgNzm6G8

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://eval.in/943297 ?

Comment: I would re-edit the post if I were you. Put one string sample and put the result you want, and there is no need for any more details about what you are doing. Edit the question to be something how to split strings in php .. or something general like that. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The next simple code use `preg_split` & `array_map` functions for split rows into number arrays:

```
$splitted = array_map(
    function($r) {
        return preg_split('/\s+/', $r);
    },
    $data
);

var_dump($splitted);
```

[Test PHP code here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=e21bae8ea9437954c1871de9d19c7c97&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)